# How to indicate the return type of a function variable

Tags: function, flutter, dart, return-type

I have declared function variable like this;

```
final Function localVideo;
```

Is there a way to indicate that this function has a return type of `Widget`?

Current code based on answers are;

```
typedef LocalVideoReturnWidget = Widget Function();

class VideoLocalOverlay extends StatefulWidget {

  final LocalVideoReturnWidget localVideo;

const VideoLocalOverlay(
      {Key key,
      this.localVideo,...
```

This gives error

```
type '() => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '() => Widget'
```

Plan to use the function as

```
child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print("Click");
                    },
                    child: widget.localVideo(),
                    ),
```

The way I have defined before works fine without any error. But for some reason I can not get the GestureDetector working. I thought it may be due to the fact return type is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this on top of file

`typedef int FunctionThatReturnInt(inputInt number);`

Another way of using `typedef`

`typedef FunctionThatReturnInt = int Function(inputInt number);`

and use the function like

`final FunctionThatReturnInt localVideo;`

inside the class or wherever you are using

Comment: getting error type '() => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '() => Widget'

Comment: how are you using localVideo() ?? could you provide some code??

Comment: Add more code to explain what i am trying to do

Comment: okay are you sure you are returning a widget in localVideo?? when you are creating VideoLocalOverlay()??

Comment: Yes it is returning. If I declare as I had before it works fine. (final Function localVideo;)

Comment: @Janaka: ```type '() => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '() => Widget'``` indicates that the return type is expecting a dynamic value not a Widget. Please show the code where you are calling this function. And also please tell the name of the package you are using.

Comment: @Janaka GestureDetector() Widget should come inside localVideo Widget for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
final Widget Function() localVideo;
```

or, if there's no argument needed, use this instead:

```
final Widget VoidCallback localVideo;
```

---

Using `typedef`:

```dart
typedef LocalVideo = Widget Function();
```

Usage:

```dart
final LocalVideo localVideo;
```

Comment: I tried it. getting error; type '() => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '() => Widget'

Comment: @Janaka Not sure how you're using it, check out my edit.

Comment: The parent is passing this function to it. For example; VideoLocalOverlay(
          localVideo: (){ return Text('Hello')},)

Answer (score 1):

First of all

```
final Function localVideo;
```

will give you an error because when you declare any thing as `final` you should initialize a value to it.

This is how you initialize a function with a return type Widget.

```
Widget localVideo(String s1, int d1){
  // function body
  Widget widgetReturn;
  return widgetReturn;
}
```

Comment: I have initialized it. When I use it the way I have mentioned it is working fine. I use the function to render a child. child:widget.localVideo(). Rendering works fine. But for some reason I can't detect gestures from it.

Comment: @Janaka: Please provide some more code. Will help.

Comment: I add more code to explain what I am trying to do